# any ideas for solve this problem useing C#

Tags: c#

hi friends i already finished the multiplication part of this.but i cant insert this "[]" to the numbers like in the above picture anyone can help me to do this using C#.

[image]

Comment: String.Format("{0}", ( i + j == 8 ) ? String.Format("[{0}]", data), data);

Comment: will work if you use for ( i ) { for ( j ) }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any your code to display data, I can't help you in fact.

So, I suppose, if you convert your numbers into strings or use string.Format (or string interpolation $""), you can add any characters. In a picture I see secondary diagonal matrix.

So, this is example of code, to display data like in a picture

```
        int diag = 9;
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Console.Write($"{i}\t");
            for (int j = 2; j < 10; j++)
            {
                if (diag != j)
                    Console.Write($"{j * i}\t");
                else
                    Console.Write($"[{j * i}]\t");
            }
            diag--;
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```